# onscroll event invoke two times for div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have use the following code snippet for bind the onscroll  event to the div

```
$div.bind("scroll", $.proxy(this._onScroll, this));

_onScroll: function (e) {
            if (this.model.enableVirtualization) {                
                var contentdiv = $(".ganttgridtreecontent");
                   this._scrollTop = contentdiv.scrollTop();
                var vScrollDist = Math.abs(this._scrollTop - this._prevScrollTop);                            
                if (vScrollDist) {
                    vScrollDir = this._prevScrollTop < this._scrollTop ? 1 : -1;                    
                    this._updateCurrentViewRange();                                                            
                    this._prevScrollTop = this._scrollTop;                   
                }

            }            
        },
```

But it will invoked two times for each scrolling action. Is there any way to prevent one scrolling action.

Comment: Can you show a working example of the problem? It sounds like the event has simply been bound twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` and `e.preventDefault();` in your function to stop the second event.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems with `$div.bind("scroll", $.proxy(this._onScroll, this));`.
Why not simply add OnScroll in div tag.

```
<div id="Scrollable content" OnScroll="Scrollfunction()">
```

Then in your javascript, define the function:

```
    function Scrollfunction()
    {
 if (this.model.enableVirtualization) {                
                var contentdiv = $(".ganttgridtreecontent");
                   this._scrollTop = contentdiv.scrollTop();
                var vScrollDist = Math.abs(this._scrollTop - this._prevScrollTop);                            
                if (vScrollDist) {
                    vScrollDir = this._prevScrollTop < this._scrollTop ? 1 : -1;                    
                    this._updateCurrentViewRange();                                                            
                    this._prevScrollTop = this._scrollTop;                   
                }

            }    
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have create the div using jquery , in my working scenorio i can not create the div tag like in your previous update. Is there any other way to resolve the problem